# Macbook Pro 16 - Cinema Display 30 , which TB3 or USB-C hub works with mini-DP to dual-link DVI-D?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, displayport, cinema-display

I just purchased the 2019 MBPro 16inch model.

Already had the Apple Cinema Display 30inch, and Apple's own mini-DP to dual-link DVI adapter.

Now looking for either a Thunderbolt 3 or USB-C hub that will work with this adapter to drive the ACD 30inch at full resolution (2560x1600).

From what I have read not all miniDP ports are equal (to put it mildly), and I would like to hear from first-hand experience what would work. (especially since some hubs are quite expensive to start with).

If there is no hub anyone can recommend, a single TB3 - female miniDP that works would be welcome as well ...

thx !